# React: Preserve local component state of tabbed content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux. Let's say that I have a (very simplified) tabbed page. Each tab has form elements and a bunch of data, like shown below:

[image]

I'm keeping the data in the Redux store, but I don't want to keep the form element state in the redux store (like whether a checkbox is checked or the value of the textbox), since they only apply to their component and are rather trivial. Instead I will store that state in their component (`TabAContent`, `TabBContent`, or `TabCContent`).

Here's the code I would use to render the content pane:

```
render() {
  var tab = null;
  if(this.props.selectedTab === 'a') {
    tab = <TabAContent />;
  }
  else if(this.props.selectedTab === 'b') {
    tab = <TabBContent />;
  }
  else if (this.props.selectedTab === 'c') {
    tab = <TabCContent />;
  }

  return tab;
}
```

Now, when I type some text into the Tab A textbox, then click on tab B, then click back, the textbox value is gone. This makes sense because the component was destroyed when I clicked on tab B. But I want that state to stick around.

In non-react, I would just have all three of the tab content panes in the DOM and toggle on/off their visibility/display:

```
<div class="content selected"></div>
<div class="content"></div> 
<div class="content"></div>
```

I'm assuming that doing something similar in React (rendering all three, but showing and hiding them) would be frowned-upon:

```
hide the other two
<TabAContent show={"true"} />
<TabBContent />
<TabCContent />
```

Another option would be to only render one at a time, but to have all three components "instantiated" somehow and assigned to a variable, so when its tab was reselected we could just stick it back in (thus preserving the state of the text box and the other form elements).

Any ideas on the best way of going about this? I realize that this **could** be solved by keeping **all** state in redux, but in my app it makes a lot more sense to keep local, simple UI state (like if a checkbox is checked) in local component state to avoid overkill.

Comment: I think you can do this with just one Tab component: check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/4G46g/ I think its headed in the right direction

Comment: There's a lot going on in that fiddle, but the main idea is that you have a container for tabs, lets TabContainer, and in there you have your Tab component, which would get style/selected based on some events...

Comment: I know a lot of time has passed but how did you solve your problem? I'm trying to do something very similar but my problem is that I can have a dynamic number of tabs (10, 20, 30 or more) and every tab has some sort of form.. I'm hidding all but active one but I'm noticing a delay cca 1 second when changing tabs when I have 20+ tabs open (tab change changes route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea with the show/hide flag is totally okey. If you want to use local state and preserve it the right way is just to keep your component live.

Its arguable thing, but I don't think Redux should be used for ui state. It's perfect to store data state in, but not ui. And ui state means nothing without ui itself. Imagine boolean value. What does it really mean? But if this boolean value is used in terms of dropdown, it's obvious, right?